# How to show different json after checking radio button value

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to show different json after click into any radio button. 'Option 1' will get option1.json etc.
Is is possible to do it without page refresh?

```
 $('#my_radio_box').change(function(){
    selected_value = $("input[name='my_options']:checked").val();
    if (selected_value == 'option 2'){
        const products = 
        [
          {id: 11,title: '2Macbook Pro', price: 2500.00, qty: 1, image: 'http://lorempixel.com/150/150/'},  
          {id: 12,title: '2Asus ROG Gaming',price: 1000.00, qty: 1,image: 'http://lorempixel.com/150/150/'},  
          {id: 13,title: '2Amazon Kindle',price: 150.00,qty: 1,image: 'http://lorempixel.com/150/150/'},  
          {id: 14,title: '2Another Product',price: 10, qty: 1, image: 'http://lorempixel.com/150/150/'},  
        ];
    }
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
                
    $('#my_radio_box').change(function(){
        selected_value = $("input[name='my_options']:checked").val();
        if (selected_value == 'option 2'){
            // const products = ...
        }
    });

});

const products = 
[
    {id: 1,title: 'Macbook Pro', price: 2500.00, qty: 1, image: 'http://lorempixel.com/150/150/'},  
    {id: 2,title: 'Asus ROG Gaming',price: 1000.00, qty: 1,image: 'http://lorempixel.com/150/150/'},  
    {id: 3,title: 'Amazon Kindle',price: 150.00,qty: 1,image: 'http://lorempixel.com/150/150/'},  
    {id: 4,title: 'Another Product',price: 10, qty: 1, image: 'http://lorempixel.com/150/150/'},  
];



function formatNumber(n, c, d, t){
    var c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c, 
            d = d === undefined ? '.' : d, 
            t = t === undefined ? ',' : t, 
            s = n < 0 ? '-' : '', 
            i = String(parseInt(n = Math.abs(Number(n) || 0).toFixed(c))), 
            j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
    return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : '') + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, '$1' + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : '');
};

// Allow the formatNumber function to be used as a filter
Vue.filter('formatCurrency', function (value) {
    return formatNumber(value, 2, '.', ',');
});

// The shopping cart component
Vue.component('shopping-cart', {
  props: ['items'],

  computed: {
    Total() {
      let total = 0;
      this.items.forEach(item => {
        total += (item.price * item.qty);
      });
      return total;
    }
  },

  methods: {
        // Remove item by its index
    removeItem(index) {
      this.items.splice(index, 1)
    }
  }
})

const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
    
  data: {
    cartItems: [],
    items : products
  },
    
  methods: {
        // Add Items to cart
    addToCart(itemToAdd) {
      let found = false;

      // Add the item or increase qty
            let itemInCart = this.cartItems.filter(item => item.id===itemToAdd.id);
            let isItemInCart = itemInCart.length > 0;

      if (isItemInCart === false) {
        this.cartItems.push(Vue.util.extend({}, itemToAdd));
      } else {
                itemInCart[0].qty += itemToAdd.qty;
            }
            
            itemToAdd.qty = 1;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.container{
    padding:20px;
    max-width:600px;
  }
  
  .input-qty {
    width: 60px;
    float: right
  }
  
  .table-cart > tr > td {
    vertical-align: middle !important;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">



<div id="app" class="container">
    <div class="text-right"><button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cartModal">Cart ({{cartItems.length}})</button></div>
        
    <form id="my_radio_box">
        <input type="radio" name="my_options" value="option 1" checked="checked" /> Option 1
        <input type="radio" name="my_options" value="option 2" /> Option 2
        <input type="radio" name="my_options" value="option 3" /> Option 3
    </form>
    
    <!-- Modal --> 
    <div class="modal fade" id="cartModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
       <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Cart</h4>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-body">
                <shopping-cart inline-template :items="cartItems">
                   <div>
                      <table class="table table-cart">
                         <tr v-for="(item, index) in items">
                            <td>{{item.title}}</td>
                            <td style="width:120px">QTY:
                               <input v-model="item.qty" class="form-control input-qty" type="number">
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-right">${{item.price | formatCurrency}}</td>
                            <td>
                               <button @click="removeItem(index)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
                            </td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr v-show="items.length === 0">
                            <td colspan="4" class="text-center">Cart is empty</td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr v-show="items.length > 0">
                            <td></td>
                            <td class="text-right">Cart Total</td>
                            <td class="text-right">${{Total | formatCurrency}}</td>
                            <td></td>
                         </tr>
                      </table>
                   </div>
                   <!-- /.container -->
                </shopping-cart>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
     
    <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-3 text-center" v-for="item in items">
             <img class="img-responsive" :src="item.image" alt="">
             <h5>{{ item.title }}</h5>
             <h6>${{ item.price | formatCurrency }}</h6>
             <p class="text-center"><input v-model="item.qty" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Qty" min="1"/></p>
                              
                <button @click="addToCart(item)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Add to Cart</button>
             </p>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: Do you mean "load a different product object from the array"?

Comment: Also why mix jQuery with VUE?

Comment: @jabaa its only for example. There will be json soon.

Comment: But the question is completely unrelated to JSON. Don't spam tags.